# how to set my field in my document to be timestamp or null in security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have rules like this

```
(user.lastEventApproval is timestamp || user.lastEventApproval is null)
```

I want to make `lastEventApproval` field in my user document to be timestamp or it can be null
but I have error like this

[image]

> mismatched input 'null' expecting IDENTIFIER
>
> An unsupported type identifier was used with the 'is' operator.
>   Received null). Expected one of
>   bool,bytes,constraint,duration,float,int,latlng,list,set,number,map,string,timestamp,path,map_diff

so can I set my field  to be timestamp or null in security rules ? maybe there is a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `null` is not a valid comparison target for the `is` keyword.  You should use `user.lastEventApproval == null` instead, if you want to know if that field contains a null value.